# Can I use a multiple-level factor as the dependent variable in a multiple regression?

Tags: r

E.g I have a class attribute "Results" with values as "Win" "Lost" "ABAN" so is there anyway I can apply regression model on that such that

```
model1 <- lm(Result~., data=data_train)
```

right now it's giving me error of "Type = factor response will be ignored"

Comment: I guess a linear model is not appropriate for factor responses. However, I'm not sure which kind of model fits best to factors with more than two - unordered? - levels.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I'm sorry that was a mistake I have already corrected in my code. means there is no way I can have factor as my response?

Comment: This sounds like a multinomial regression. Take a look at the `mlogit` and `mnlogit` packages.

Comment: The `nnet` package also has a `multinom` function. I don't know how it compares to `mlogit` and `mnlogit`